# Is there a way to destructure values inside a javascript object?

Tags: javascript, typescript, redux

Lets say I have an object with constants

```
const FETCH_DATA = {
  REQUESTED: 'FETCH_DATA_REQUESTED',
}
```

And now I want to use them in another object

```
const fetchData = {
  requested() {
    return {
      type: FETCH_DATA.REQUESTED
    };
  },
}
```

But I don't want to retype the whole constant name each time.

Is it possible to do destructure? Something like this, only this doesn't work.

```
const fetchData = {
  {REQUESTED}: FETCH_DATA,
  requested() {
    return {
      type: REQUESTED
    }
  }
}
```

I can't put it outside the object due to REQUESTED being too general for the global scope as I have multiple REQUESTED constants.

Comment: Probably you would have separated your code for a large piece of software, meaning that you would probably not have duplicates in a single file, if that is the case well then destructure on import, it that is not the case, well, then why not make a "dynamic" action type, just creating a function that makes the same type based on the parameter (btw, don't know what I did wrong to get your serial dv yesterday, suggesting to structure your code better isn't a harsh comment)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a module (= file) containing your constants and then export them as constants:

FetchDataContants.ts

```
export const REQUESTED = 'REQUESTED';
export const MYCONST = 'just an example';
```

then in another file…

```
import { REQUESTED, MYCONST } from './FetchDataConstants';

requested() {
  return { type: REQUESTED }
}
```

or import all like so...

```
import * as c from './FetchDataConstants';

requested() {
  return { type: c.REQUESTED }
}
```